# How to change the following bean properties at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the following Spring xml file for generating different views for different file formats. I have two properties one *url* and *datasource*. I want the *url* to be changed at run time i.e. I want to use different `jrxml` files rather just one static one.

```
    <bean id="pdfReport"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
        p:url="classpath:tree-template.jrxml" p:reportDataKey="datasource" />

    <bean id="xlsReport"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsXlsView"
        p:url="classpath:tree-template.jrxml" p:reportDataKey="datasource" />

    <bean id="htmlReport"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsHtmlView"
        p:url="classpath:tree-template.jrxml" p:reportDataKey="datasource" />

    <bean id="csvReport"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsCsvView"
        p:url="classpath:tree-template.jrxml" p:reportDataKey="datasource" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieve the bean from your context

```
ApplicationContext context = ...;
JasperReportsCsvView view = (JasperReportsCsvView) context.getBean("csvReport");
```

and use its setter to change the property

```
view.setUrl(someNewValue);
```

Do the same thing for each bean. If your beans share a common super type, you can use [`ApplicationContext#getBeansOfType(Class)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansOfType-java.lang.Class-) to retrieve all of them at once as a `Map`. You then iterate over the entries and change the view's property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I used the following code: JasperReportsPdfView view = (JasperReportsPdfView) applicationContext.getBean("pdfReport");
  view.setUrl("D:\\Jasper JRXML\\Template.jrxml");
  modelAndView = new ModelAndView(view, parameterMap); But the view which is a spirng bean is not being changed. I am using MVC pattern.

Comment: @BRS Ah, it seems that those Jasper Reports views load their resource form the URL when they are created and re-use for the duration of their life cycle. You will need to create a new bean to use a different template.

Comment: So for each of the reports I should have a separate class and make a bean as and when I require it by setting the jrxml and datasource right? Then how useful is DI here?

Comment: @BRS That's almost right. The problem is that those `View` classes need more than just the datasource and jrxml. They need access to the `ApplicationContext`. I don't think these `View` types are appropriate for changing templates. Consider looking into a different Jasper Reports templating engine.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will think of using japser api and making separate classes. If you know any resources please do let me know.

Comment: @BRS You're welcome. Unfortunately, I've never used Jasper Reports with Spring. However, you might want to look into [Open Reports](http://oreports.com/). It's a dead project but you may get some help out of its use of Jasper Reports.